# Ideals in a Quadratic Number Field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Show the ideal $I=\langle4,2+2\sqrt{-29}\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-29}]$ satisfies the equality $\langle8\rangle=I^{2}$ of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-29}]$.

I tried to factorise $x^{2}+29$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ but cannot manage to reach $I$ this way.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Note first that $I = (2)J$, where $J = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-29})$. Then it suffices to show $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-29})^2 = (2)$. If we square this ideal, we have $$J^2 = (4, 2 + 2\sqrt{-29}, -28 + 2\sqrt{-29}) = (2)(2, 1 + \sqrt{-29}, -14 + \sqrt{-29}).$$ We need to show that the ideal $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-29}, -14 + \sqrt{-29})$ is really all of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-29}]$. To see this, we just play with the generators:
\begin{align*}
(2, 1 + \sqrt{-29}, -14 + \sqrt{-29}) &= (2, 1 + \sqrt{-29}, \sqrt{-29})\\
&= (2,1,\sqrt{-29})\\
&= \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-29}].
\end{align*}
Then the desired equality follows: $J^2 = (2)\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-29}] = (2)$, so $I^2 = (4)(2) = (8)$.